# Date conversion failed with apache-nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I use `UpdateRecord` processor to change date format.

```
Recrod-Reader :  CSVReader

                -> Schema Access Strategy : Use String Fields From Header
```

```
Replacement Value Strategy : Literal Values

/Date_time_col             : ${field.value:toDate("yyyyMMddhhmmss","GMT"):format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")}
```

My input data : `20200311163918`

Output : `2020-03-11 10:09:18`

Expected : `2020-03-11 16:39:18`

Comment: add "GMT" for `format`

Comment: @Lamanus you mean `:format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss","GMT")`

Comment: @Lamanus This fixed my issue, can you please share this as an asnwer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can set the timezone when you use the `format` function.

```
${field.value:toDate("yyyyMMddhhmmss","GMT"):format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", "GMT")}
```

This will fix your problem. :)